# Finding k smallest/largest elements in array with focus on memory

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, memory, arduino

I have an unsigned int array with `n` elements (with `n` being at most around 20-25 elements). Duplicates are possible.

I know that the smallest `k` values are of type `A` and the other (larger) `n-k` values are of type `B`. In order to differentiate between `A` and `B` I need to find the indices of the `k` smallest values (or the `n-k` largest values, depending on what is easier/faster). The original array must not be altered as the element's index contains information.

There are multiple solutions for this problem on the web (e.g. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/)). However, most of them try to optimize processing time and neglect memory usage.

As I am implementing the code in C++ on a (Arduino based) microcontroller, I have to focus on low memory usage and, if necessary, take a slightly longer processing time. I therefore feel unsafe using pointers and recursion (maybe I wouldn't if I knew more about it, but in fact I don't).

Can you recommend which algorithm would be best for that task (an implementation is welcome but not essential)?

Comment: [Quick Select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) would be one, the link explains it in detail.

Comment: The sorting + selecting the first k elements approach is not good enough for you?

Comment: What is wrong with the min/max heap in the link you provided: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/ ? The heap has the same size as the final output. Treat the output array as heap.

Comment: For 20-25 elements the fasted thing and using minimal RAM you can do is a linear search on a sorted array. At least if your embedded system is something like a MIPS or Cortex M4 or higher. For lower a binary search will be faster.

Comment: *"I know that the smallest k values are of type A"*, so `std::partition` or `std::copy_if` seems do the job.

Comment: @Jarod42 I use an ATmega328P which has 2000 bytes of RAM. General statements mostly advice to avoid `std` libraries...

Comment: @SamerTufail at the moment I have a quicksort solution implemented in my code. However, the fact that it uses both: recursion and pointers makes me uncomfortable about the possibility to run out of memory (my ATmega328P only has 2000 bytes)

Comment: @speendo what part makes you uncomfortable? you can profile memory usage for various test cases. Quickselect utilitzes the partition part of the quicksort and stops as soon as you reach your K elements, so you don't sort the full array.

Comment: @SamerTufail I don't know much about memory allocation, but as far as I know pointers make the memory usage unpredictable for the compiler and recursion would (in the worst case) double memory usage with every iteration. But I might be wrong of course.

Comment: @speendo If you are worried about dynamic memory allocations you can use [placement new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax). If you are worried about recursion you can write an iterative version by using the c++ stack and doing exactly what the call stack would do or profile your stack usage.

Comment: @user6556709 sounds interesting, but what should I search for?

Comment: @MichaelVeksler The Heap Sort algorithm is also recursive. Maybe it's because of my lack of knowledge but I fear that a recursive method will blow up my memory. Is this fear unfounded?

Comment: @SamerTufail although I believe that this is possible, this sounds very sophisticated and probably exceeds my young C++ capabilities ;)

Comment: @speendo heap sort is bounded by O(log(heapSize)). So for 32 elements or less, the max recursion depth is 5

Comment: If you can't use full std. you might still use implementation of needed function. and very few algorithms (from `<algorithm>`) does memory allocation, and `std::partition` or `std::copy_if` don't allocate.

Comment: I figured out a method where I would make a second `bool` array to mark elements used already. I would then iterate `k` times over the original array and each time search for the lowest value that is not marked as used yet. These values should be summed up to mark the border between type `A` and `B`. A small efficiency improvement would be to fist check if `k < n-k` as otherwise it would be faster to sum up the largest values instead. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Why don't you make a copy of the array and use a classic bubblesort? It is slow, but you don't seem to care about speed. It can be implemented without using pointers nor recursion. The memory footprint will be n (the array size, as you'll be making a copy), if you manage to use a xor-based swap function.